# How to rank rows with the top density based on their length in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql I have table A that has columns id, length, density and class

Basically I want to fill out the class column based on ranks. For simplification sake let's say the total length is 50 meters

class 1 will have the top 10% of rows that lengths summed up to 5 meters that have  highest density

class 2 will have the range from 10% to 20% of the next tier of lengths, summed up to 5 again.

class 3 from 20% to 30%

And so on

With the end result, if I sum classes 1 and 2 I will have 10 meters and 20% of the total density

Edit: tried using ntile but having problems, first of all updating a colum didn't work because it return more than one feature (??) so tried creating a new table:

```
create table table2 as
select *,   ntile(10) over (order by density) as ntile
from table1
```

When I sum the length it gives me 19M, but then I do

```
select sum(length) from pedro_test.board_dec17_london_road_copy2 where ntile = 8
```

It returns 2.5M instead of 1.9M, which should be 10%

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       1 + (10 * running_length / (total_length + 1))::int as decile
from (select t.*,
             sum(length) over () as total_length,
             sum(length) over (order by density desc) as running_length
      from t
     ) t;
```

I should note that Postgres has other functions such as `NTILE()` and `PERCENTILE()` which can also be used for this purpose.

Comment: Umm something is wrong with that, it only returns 2 deciles instead of 10. And it doesn't work with my update update table set class = (select t.*, 1 + (running_length / (total_length + 1))::int as decile from (select t.*, sum(length) over () as total_length, sum(length) over (order by density desc) as running_length from table t ) t)